# Is it possible to include multiple paragraphs in spoilers?

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown

I can't find a way to show multiple paragraphs in a spoiler tag. I had to resort to including superfluous headings between the paragraphs (or rather between the text and image, which I did not want to show the images on the same line as the text). Horizontal lines also work, but I would like to include a paragraph break within the spoiler itself.

> If I do this, it doesn't show multiple paragraphs.
>
>  second paragraph

---

> ! If I do this, it breaks the spoiler code entirely.
>
> ! second paragraph

---

> To compare:
>
> This is how you do it with quotes. Analogous to the second example above.

```
First example:
>! a
>!
>! b

Second example:
>! a

>! b
```

Alternately, is there a way to force an image to display on its own line? This was the reason I attempted to use a paragraph break in the first place.